# Cannot access Outline VPN on CentOS

Tags: linux, vpn, centos, iptables, outline

I installed Outline VPN a few times on Ubuntu servers and each time it was fast and easy. Now I'm trying to install it to CentOS and the Outline VPN shell script executes smoothly and with no errors:

```
sudo bash -c "$(wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Jigsaw-Code/outline-server/master/src/server_manager/install_scripts/install_server.sh)"
```

But Outline Manager app on my computer cannot connect to the fresh installed Outline VPN server.

The shell script given me two port numbers, I try to open allow these ports in iptables:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp –dport 21256 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp –dport 30453 -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
```

Connection to the server itself is stable (I have there SSH, Apache and MariaDB — everything is working, only Outline VPN isn't).

Please let me know which logs I need to check and attach here maybe. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right, installing Outline on a CentOS is a little bit more difficult comparing to Ubuntu.

**1. Check if the ports are used by other service:**

```c
lsof -i -P | grep 21256
lsof -i -P | grep 30453
```

If so, run the Outline script once again — it will generate new pair of ports.

**2. Check if the ports are not allowed by the firewall:**

```c
iptables-save | grep 21256
iptables-save | grep 30453
```

We expect an empty output.

**3. Add the following lines to the services file:**

```
nano /etc/services
```

```c
outline 21256/tcp
outline 30453/tcp
```

**4. Add the ports to the firewall and reload the firewall to apply new rules:**

```c
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=21256/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=30453/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Don't forget to copy a new JSON string from an output of the shell script. Copy and paste it to Outline Manager and try to connect again, it should work.